Create a dataframe from numpy array and parameters
Running Elastic Net simulations by varying a couple parameters and looking to save output coefficients to a dataframe for potential review later.
Ultimately looking to save off a dataframe with two parameter identifier columns (ie, 'alpha', 'l1_ratio') and a number of other columns for the resulting coefficients for the model fit with those parameters.
'alpha' is a float (varying from .1 to 1000 in increments) and 'l1_ratio' is a float from 0 to 1.  'coefs' is a numpy array that I'd like to expand into individual columns for each coefficient value (total number will stay fixed, say 5 for this simple case).
For instance:
alpha = .1
l1_ratio = .5
coefs = array([-1.30, -0.45, .04, .65, -0.88])

would result in a row record in the final dataframe of:
    alpha   l1_ratio    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   .1  .5  -1.30   -0.45   .04 .65 -0.88

I'll ultimately loop over and place additional rows for each scenario.  Would also prefer not to label coefficient columns manually as there can be dozens depending on the situation--leaving column header empty is fine.
How would I do this?

I imagine you will generate all data points iteratively. However, DataFrames don't like to be grown this way. Performance of adding new rows repeatedly is terrible.
Assuming logic the function that will produce the new data points, I would use a dictionary to collect them, and create the DataFrame once in the end:
data = {}
for alpha, l1_ratio, coeffs in logic():
    data[(alpha, l1_ratio)] = coeffs

df = (pd.DataFrame(data).T
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f'c{x+1}')
        .rename_axis(['alpha', 'l1_ratio'])
        .reset_index() # optional
      )

Variant to generate the dataframe:
df = (pd.DataFrame(data.keys(), columns=['alpha', 'l1_ratio'])
        .join(pd.DataFrame(data.values())
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'c{x+1}'))
      )

Example output:
   alpha  l1_ratio   c1    c2    c3    c4    c5
0    0.1       0.5 -1.3 -0.45  0.04  0.65 -0.88
1    0.2       0.5 -1.3 -0.45  0.04  0.65 -0.88

